# How to import 14 digits integer column into R from SQLite

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, r-dbi

I have a SQLite table containing a DATETIME column expressed in milliseconds since epoch. That is a 14 digits integer. I import the table into R with the following

```
  require(DBI)
  con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = database)
  query <- dbSendQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM ", table, ";", sep="")) 
  result <- fetch(query, n = -1, encoding="utf-8")
  dbClearResult(query)
  dbDisconnect(con)
  return(result)
```

yet my column is imported as 32-bit integer column (up to 10 digits) with nefarious consequences.

How should I specify the target file type for the column?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to cast it to a floating point number (after possibly dividing by 1e3), which R will read as a `numeric`.

You can then transform the numeric value into a standard Datetime in R via `as.POSIXct()`.

In case you can consider alternatives, the RPostgreSQL interface to PostgreSQL handles the SQL datetime to R Datetime transparently; the RMySQL one does not.

Comment: `You should try to cast it to a floating point number (after possibly dividing by 1e3)`, do you mean **before** importing into R?

Comment: Yes, the cast has to happen at SQL level so that R won't try importing as an integer.